# Mooncows, parrot, magic turnstile

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I believe this book was called "The Enchanted Parcel" but I can't find any book by that name.  It was about a group of children who find a brown paper package containing a talking parrot, who guides them through a cave and a magic turnstile into a fantasy land.  Some of the most memorable inhabitants of the fantasy land were "Mooncows", giant enchanted snails who exuded a useful substance like magical sheets of plastic.  I read it in the 80's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*The Talking Parcel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Talking_Parcel), by Gerald Durrell.

> *The Talking Parcel* (also published as *The Battle for Castle Cockatrice*) is  a 1974 book by Gerald Durrell in which children are transported to the fantasy land of Mythologia to save it from cockatrices. They are aided by a talking parrot and encounter many other magical creatures, including a mooncalf.

[ISFDB link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?26598)
[Goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/401769.The_Talking_Parcel)

Comment: Thanks! My search terms must have been just wrong enough to mess up the results.